# UIImageView Content Mode for responsive image view frame

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit

I have an image thats a particular height and width and its designed in such a way where its content is meant to be displayed at a minimum height, and as the height increases more of the image is allowed to be seen (meant to clip at the frame). This is because we wanted to serve up one image, but depending on device size, the frame can get display as much of the photo necessary.

My question is whats the best way to manage the content mode of the UIImageView to allow for this as well as how should the imageview constraints should be managed. Any advice? My original thought was to have the content mode be 'center' and use a combination of greater and less than height constraints to achieve the height part.

The red rect shows the uiimageview frame at its small screen size (iPhone SE), green is at normal size (iPhone) and orange is for plus devices.

Perhaps the community has a better solve for this?

[image: UIImageView frames]

Comment: tried aspect ratio ??

Comment: It depends on how you want to show your image. In most case, `aspectFill` would fit.